Infinite 2D block world chunk system with physics
I am coding an Infinite 2D block world chunk system with physics for fun. I am worried mainly about performance and code structure. I found that when I added more Perlin noise it made the performance really bad so if there were a faster way to create terrain that would be good.
game.py:
import pygame
import world

MOVEMENT_SPEED = 128


class Game:
    def __init__(self, title, window_size, fps):
        self.title = title
        self.window_size = window_size
        self.FPS = fps

        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.window_size)
        self.window_rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), self.window_size)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        pygame.display.set_caption(self.title)

        self.running = True

        self.world = world.World(8, 10)
        self.cam_x = 0
        self.cam_y = 0
        self.draw_area = (
            int(self.window_size[0] // world.CHUNK_TOTAL_SIZE) + 2,
            int(self.window_size[1] // world.CHUNK_TOTAL_SIZE) + 2,
        )

        self.player = self.world.create_entity(
            0,
            pygame.Vector2(0, -512),
        )

        self.cam_on_player = True

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            self.do_frame()

        self.quit_pygame()

    def do_frame(self):
        self.handle_events()
        self.game_logic()

        self.draw()
        pygame.display.update(self.window_rect)

        self.clock.tick(self.FPS)

    def quit_pygame(self):
        pygame.quit()

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                print(self.clock.get_fps())
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.running = False
                if (event.key == pygame.K_w) and self.player.collide_y:
                    self.player.force += pygame.Vector2(0, -10)
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    self.cam_on_player = not self.cam_on_player

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.cam_x += MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.cam_x -= MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.cam_y += MOVEMENT_SPEED
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.cam_y -= MOVEMENT_SPEED
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.player.force += pygame.Vector2(-2, 0)
        elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.player.force += pygame.Vector2(2, 0)

        self.world.load_pos = (
            int(-self.cam_x // world.CHUNK_TOTAL_SIZE),
            int(-self.cam_y // world.CHUNK_TOTAL_SIZE),
        )

    def draw(self):
        draw_offset_x = self.cam_x + self.window_rect.centerx
        draw_offset_y = self.cam_y + self.window_rect.centery
        # draw_offset = pygame.Vector2(draw_offset_x, draw_offset_y)

        start_chunk_x = int((-draw_offset_x) // world.CHUNK_TOTAL_SIZE)
        start_chunk_y = int((-draw_offset_y) // world.CHUNK_TOTAL_SIZE)

        chunk_poses = [
            (x, y)
            for x in range(start_chunk_x, start_chunk_x + self.draw_area[0])
            for y in range(start_chunk_y, start_chunk_y + self.draw_area[1])
        ]

        chunk_textures = self.world.get_chunk_textures(chunk_poses)

        self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        for i, chunk_texture in enumerate(chunk_textures):
            chunk_pos = chunk_poses[i]
            self.screen.blit(
                chunk_texture,
                (
                    (chunk_pos[0] * world.CHUNK_TOTAL_SIZE) + draw_offset_x,
                    (chunk_pos[1] * world.CHUNK_TOTAL_SIZE) + draw_offset_y,
                ),
            )
        for entity in self.world.entitys:
            self.screen.blit(
                entity.image,
                (
                    int(entity.pos.x) + draw_offset_x,
                    int(entity.pos.y) + draw_offset_y,
                ),
            )

    def game_logic(self):
        self.world.load_chunks()
        for entity in self.world.entitys:
            entity.update()
        if self.cam_on_player:
            self.cam_x = -int((self.player.pos.x + (self.player.size[0] / 2)))
            self.cam_y = -int((self.player.pos.y + (self.player.size[1] / 2)))


new_game = Game("2D Block World", (1280, 640), 0)
new_game.run()


world.py:
import math
import random
import perlin_noise
import pygame

BLOCK_TEXTURE_NAMES = [
    "textures/void.png",
    "textures/air.png",
    "textures/grass_block.png",
    "textures/dirt.png",
    "textures/stone.png",
    "textures/sandstone.png",
    "textures/sand.png",
    "textures/bedrock.png",
    "textures/oak_log.png",
    "textures/oak_leaves.png",
    "textures/cobblestone.png",
    "textures/oak_leaves_over_log.png",
]
BLOCK_COLLISION_DATA = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
ENTITY_TEXTURE_NAMES = ["textures/player.png"]
ENTITY_SIZES = [(32, 64)]
ENTITY_HITBOX_DATA = [[(pygame.Vector2(8, 0), pygame.Vector2(16, 64))]]
# ENTITY_ARMS_TEXTURE_NAMES

GRAVITY = pygame.Vector2(0, 1)
RESISTANCE = pygame.Vector2(0.8, 0.99)

BACKGROUND_COLOR = (0, 200, 255)

BLOCK_SIZE = 8
CHUNK_SIZE = 32
CHUNK_TOTAL_SIZE = BLOCK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE
CHUNK_RANGE = range(CHUNK_SIZE)

EMPTY_CHUNK_DATA = [0] * (CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE)

BEDROCK = 256
SOIL_AMOUNT = 16
FREQUENCY = 250
AMPLITUDE = 200


def load_texture(texture, size):
    return pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(texture).convert_alpha(), size)


def _2d_to_1d(pos):
    return (pos[0] * CHUNK_SIZE) + pos[1]


def block_to_chunk(block_pos):
    chunk_x, block_x = divmod(block_pos[0], CHUNK_SIZE)
    chunk_y, block_y = divmod(block_pos[1], CHUNK_SIZE)
    return (chunk_x, chunk_y), (block_x, block_y)


class Textures:
    def __init__(self):
        self.block_textures = [
            load_texture(texture_name, (BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE))
            for texture_name in BLOCK_TEXTURE_NAMES
        ]
        self.empty_chunk_surface = pygame.Surface(
            (CHUNK_TOTAL_SIZE, CHUNK_TOTAL_SIZE)
        ).convert_alpha()
        self.background_block_surface = pygame.Surface(
            (BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE)
        ).convert_alpha()
        self.entity_textures = [
            load_texture(texture_name, ENTITY_SIZES[i])
            for i, texture_name in enumerate(ENTITY_TEXTURE_NAMES)
        ]

        self.empty_chunk_surface.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
        self.background_block_surface.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)


class Entity:
    def __init__(
        self,
        world,
        entity_number,
        init_pos=pygame.Vector2(),
        init_vel=pygame.Vector2(),
        init_force=pygame.Vector2(),
    ):
        self.world = world
        self.size = pygame.Vector2(ENTITY_SIZES[entity_number])
        self.image = self.world.textures.entity_textures[entity_number]
        self.hitbox_data = ENTITY_HITBOX_DATA[entity_number]

        self.pos = init_pos
        self.vel = init_vel
        self.force = init_force

        self.collide_x = False
        self.collide_y = False
        self.collide_xy = False
        self.stuck = False

    def get_blocks_collide(self):
        blocks = []
        for start_pos, size in self.hitbox_data:
            start_pos_block = (start_pos + self.test_pos) / BLOCK_SIZE
            end_pos_block = (size + start_pos + self.test_pos) / BLOCK_SIZE

            block_range_x = range(math.floor(start_pos_block.x), math.floor(end_pos_block.x)+1)
            block_range_y = range(math.floor(start_pos_block.y), math.floor(end_pos_block.y)+1)

            blocks += [
                (block_x, block_y) for block_x in block_range_x for block_y in block_range_y
            ]

        return self.world.get_blocks(blocks)

    def collide(self):
        self.blocks_collide = self.get_blocks_collide()
        self.collide_data = [
            BLOCK_COLLISION_DATA[block] for block in self.blocks_collide
        ]

    def test(self):
        self.test_pos = self.pos.copy()
        self.collide()

    def test_xy(self):
        self.test_pos = self.pos.copy()
        self.test_pos += self.vel
        self.collide()

    def test_x(self):
        self.test_pos = self.pos.copy()
        self.test_pos.x += self.vel.x
        self.collide()

    def test_y(self):
        self.test_pos = self.pos.copy()
        self.test_pos.y += self.vel.y
        self.collide()

    def update(self):
        self.vel += self.force + GRAVITY
        self.vel = self.vel.elementwise() * RESISTANCE
        self.force = pygame.Vector2()

        self.collide_x = False
        self.collide_y = False
        self.collide_xy = False
        self.stuck = False

        self.test()
        if 1 in self.collide_data:
            self.vel = pygame.Vector2()
            self.stuck = True
            return

        self.test_xy()
        if 1 in self.collide_data:
            self.collide_xy = True
            self.test_x()
            if 1 in self.collide_data:
                self.vel.x = 0
                self.collide_x = True
            self.test_y()
            if 1 in self.collide_data:
                self.vel.y = 0
                self.collide_y = True

        if not (self.collide_x or self.collide_y) and self.collide_xy:
            self.vel.y = 0
            self.collide_y = True

        self.pos += self.vel


class World:
    def __init__(self, load_distance, seed=0):
        self.flat = True
        if seed:
            self.perlin_noise = perlin_noise.PerlinNoise(octaves=1.3, seed=seed)
            self.flat = False

        self.textures = Textures()
        self.chunks = {}
        self.chunk_textures = {}
        self.load_pos = (0, 0)
        self.load_distance = load_distance

        self.entitys = []

    def create_entity(
        self,
        entity_number,
        init_pos=pygame.Vector2(),
        init_vel=pygame.Vector2(),
        init_force=pygame.Vector2(),
    ):
        new_entity = Entity(
            self,
            entity_number, 
            init_pos,
            init_vel,
            init_force,
        )
        self.entitys.append(new_entity)
        return new_entity

    def load_chunks(self):
        chunk_range_x = range(
            self.load_pos[0] - self.load_distance,
            self.load_pos[0] + self.load_distance + 1,
        )
        chunk_range_y = range(
            self.load_pos[1] - self.load_distance,
            self.load_pos[1] + self.load_distance + 1,
        )
        chunks_in_range = [(x, y) for x in chunk_range_x for y in chunk_range_y]

        chunks_to_load = []
        chunks_to_unload = []

        for chunk_pos in chunks_in_range:
            if chunk_pos not in self.chunks.keys():
                chunks_to_load.append(chunk_pos)

        for chunk_pos in self.chunks.keys():
            if chunk_pos not in chunks_in_range:
                chunks_to_unload.append(chunk_pos)

        distances_from_load_pos = [
            abs(self.load_pos[0] - chunk_pos[0]) + abs(self.load_pos[1] - chunk_pos[1])
            for chunk_pos in chunks_to_load
        ]
        if distances_from_load_pos:
            best_distance = min(distances_from_load_pos)
            self.load_chunk(
                chunks_to_load[distances_from_load_pos.index(best_distance)]
            )

        for chunk_pos in chunks_to_unload:
            self.chunks.pop(chunk_pos)
            self.chunk_textures.pop(chunk_pos)

    def load_chunk(self, chunk_pos):
        self.chunks[chunk_pos] = self.generate_data(chunk_pos)
        self.chunk_textures[chunk_pos] = self.generate_chunk_texture(chunk_pos)

    def get_blocks(self, block_poses):
        blocks = []
        for block_pos in block_poses:
            chunk_pos, local_block_pos = block_to_chunk(block_pos)
            if chunk_pos in self.chunks.keys():
                blocks.append(self.chunks[chunk_pos][_2d_to_1d(local_block_pos)])
            else:
                blocks.append(0)

        return blocks

    def get_chunk_textures(self, chunk_poses):
        chunk_textures = []
        for chunk_pos in chunk_poses:
            if chunk_pos in self.chunk_textures.keys():
                chunk_textures.append(self.chunk_textures[chunk_pos])
            else:
                chunk_textures.append(self.textures.empty_chunk_surface)

        return chunk_textures


    def generate_data(self, pos):
        data = EMPTY_CHUNK_DATA[:]
        chunk_block_x = pos[0] * CHUNK_SIZE
        chunk_block_y = pos[1] * CHUNK_SIZE

        surface = 0
        for x in CHUNK_RANGE:
            block_x = x + chunk_block_x
            if not self.flat:
                surface = int(self.perlin_noise.noise(block_x / FREQUENCY) * AMPLITUDE)
            for y in CHUNK_RANGE:
                data_pos = _2d_to_1d((x, y))
                block_y = y + chunk_block_y
                if block_y == surface:
                    block_type = 2
                elif block_y > surface and block_y <= surface + SOIL_AMOUNT:
                    block_type = 3
                elif block_y > surface + SOIL_AMOUNT and block_y < BEDROCK:
                    block_type = 4
                elif block_y == BEDROCK:
                    block_type = 7
                elif block_y > BEDROCK:
                    block_type = 0
                else:
                    block_type = 1
                data[data_pos] = block_type

        return data

    def generate_chunk_texture(self, pos):
        chunk_texture = self.textures.empty_chunk_surface.copy()
        chunk_data = self.chunks[pos]

        for x in CHUNK_RANGE:
            for y in CHUNK_RANGE:
                data = chunk_data[_2d_to_1d((x, y))]
                blit_pos = (x * BLOCK_SIZE, y * BLOCK_SIZE)
                chunk_texture.blit(self.textures.block_textures[data], blit_pos)

        return chunk_texture


profile output:
         2111948 function calls (2106002 primitive calls) in 6.467 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    6.468    6.468 game.py:1(<module>)
      271    0.017    0.000    3.335    0.012 game.py:123(game_logic)
        1    0.002    0.002    4.915    4.915 game.py:37(run)
      271    0.010    0.000    4.839    0.018 game.py:43(do_frame)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.075    0.075 game.py:52(quit_pygame)
      271    0.011    0.000    0.045    0.000 game.py:55(handle_events)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 game.py:7(Game)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.431    0.431 game.py:8(__init__)
      271    0.039    0.000    1.076    0.004 game.py:88(draw)
      271    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 game.py:96(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.018    0.018 world.py:1(<module>)
      750    0.011    0.000    0.201    0.000 world.py:101(get_blocks_collide)
      750    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 world.py:108(<listcomp>)
      750    0.005    0.000    0.211    0.000 world.py:114(collide)
      750    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 world.py:116(<listcomp>)
      271    0.001    0.000    0.085    0.000 world.py:120(test)
      271    0.001    0.000    0.074    0.000 world.py:124(test_xy)
      104    0.001    0.000    0.028    0.000 world.py:129(test_x)
      104    0.000    0.000    0.028    0.000 world.py:134(test_y)
      271    0.008    0.000    0.223    0.001 world.py:139(update)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 world.py:174(World)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.009    0.009 world.py:175(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 world.py:189(create_entity)
      271    0.402    0.001    3.095    0.011 world.py:208(load_chunks)
      271    0.027    0.000    0.027    0.000 world.py:217(<listcomp>)
      271    0.050    0.000    0.066    0.000 world.py:230(<listcomp>)
      271    0.003    0.000    2.568    0.009 world.py:244(load_chunk)
      750    0.091    0.000    0.181    0.000 world.py:248(get_blocks)
      271    0.011    0.000    0.015    0.000 world.py:259(get_chunk_textures)
      271    0.393    0.001    1.197    0.004 world.py:270(generate_data)
      271    0.470    0.002    1.368    0.005 world.py:299(generate_chunk_texture)
       13    0.000    0.000    0.008    0.001 world.py:43(load_texture)
   588668    0.317    0.000    0.317    0.000 world.py:47(_2d_to_1d)
    33750    0.041    0.000    0.058    0.000 world.py:51(block_to_chunk)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 world.py:57(Textures)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.008    0.008 world.py:58(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.007    0.007 world.py:59(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 world.py:69(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 world.py:78(Entity)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 world.py:79(__init__)

I am using python 3.8
Images:
[













]

try adding an _xy_to_1d(x, y) and using that where currently there is a call _2d_to_1d((x, y))

also i have magic numbers in world.generate_data() and game.handle_events()......

Caching
One thing to consider is caching the results of:
surface = int(self.perlin_noise.noise(block_x / FREQUENCY) * AMPLITUDE

since as of now it's being recomputed with the same values for each vertical chunk.
Generate Chunk Texture
I think for air and void you are blitting clear images in generate_chunk_texture. I tried adding an if statement that skips blitting for those blocks. Doesn't do much but it is a bit faster and looks exactly the same as far as I can tell.
Reduce Limit of Detection
With your current limit of detection the chunks go way off the screen. If you take J_H's suggestion of generating the chunks from a separate process I think it is a good idea to generate chunks a decent ways off screen. As it stands though there is a limit to how fast a player can go in a single frame because of "RESISTANCE" and one chunk is generated every frame. So the way things currently are there is no need for limit of detection to be more than 3 but you could use 4 and still reduce the amount of computation by half.
Misleading Name
load_chunks finds all the chunks it needs to load but only actually loads one chunk. Not sure what a better name would be but the current is misleading. Maybe load_nearest_chunk or something along those lines.
Physics
I tried to run your code and didn't have too bad of performance issues on my machine. Your movement is calculated once per frame and isn't dependent on the amount of time that has past. This had a funny result where everything was extremely quick for me i.e. I would run at mach 10 until I got caught on terrain then hit jump and instantly go up and down. You could measure the time between frames and pass that into your update function then using the time delta times velocity to calculate position. Alternatively I just capped the fps at 120 and things looked reasonable (I was running at 400fps initially and 600fps after some minor changes)
numpy
I liked a bunch of J_H's suggestions but I'll mention this one as well because there are a lot of things you can do with it. You will be able to use a 2D array instead of having to convert _2D_to_1D when figuring out indexing.
I would suggest having a chunk texture for all blocks cobblestone and at the start of generate_chunk_texture doing something like:
if (chunk_data <= 0).all():
    # every block is just air, no need to blit blank blocks on it
    return self.textures.empty_chunk_surface.copy()
elif (chunk_data == 4).all():
    # every block is cobblestone, use pre-generated cobblestone chunk
    return self.textures.stone_chunk_surface.copy()

To avoid the double for loops for with the blitting being performed for common chunks.
I think there are changes that could be made in generate_data as well, using slicing to assign sections of the array instead of having the inner loop along y.

awesome this answer has told me a lot, mainly that i have 60fps on a potato computer but you have 400! what specs?

also i have figured out a better system for loading that loads only a certain percentage of chunks at a time, it is still slow so i will think about numpy...

lol, I only mentioned my fps to make the point that the way movement is done will result in the character moving at different speeds on different machines, not to make fun of your potato. Have you tried lowering limit of detection to not go so far off screen? You can probably double your fps just changing one number.

when you say limit of detection do you mean load_distance in world.world? if so i want to increase it and still get good fps.

algorithm

when I added more Perlin noise it made the performance really bad

You might consider switching to a related form of noise, as Wikipedia asserts that

simplex noise alleviates some of the problems with Perlin's "classic noise", among them computational complexity ...

memory vs CPU
There is an opportunity to trade RAM for cycles.
Increase BLOCK_SIZE by a factor of 2 or 4,
and make a corresponding reduction in CHUNK_SIZE.
The idea is to do fewer generate_chunk_texture() calls,
using bigger BLITs.
JIT
It would be worth your while to add type signatures
to function signatures, so
mypy --strict
lints cleanly. Now your functions are better documented,
so humans can more easily read and understand them.
As a bonus, that also sets you up for
numba
compilation using @jit or @jitclass decorators.
The 3.8 bytecode interpreter you're using is on the old side;
in fact it is no longer a supported version.
You may find some speedup just by switching to a more modern
interpreter, as there has been some focus on (small) incremental
speedups with each year's release.
numpy
Consider phrasing the whole thing in terms of
NDArrays,
so python can vectorize instead of looping.
There should be little need for chunking,
once you've done some (lo res) initialization of SOIL vs BEDROCK values.

the whole point of optimising is getting it working fast at block size of 8...

I will try the simplex noise at the very least, is there anything wrong with the achual code?

"anything wrong?" Not quite wrong, but suboptimal given your need for speed. It isn't type annotated, it isn't JIT'ed, and it doesn't access vectorized BLAS code via numpy. There is room to improve, without spending much effort.

simplex noise didn't improve it...

I'm going to have to pause the game whenever it needs to generate more land.... I get 10 fps when i try adding caves.

Let a background task generate land on the periphery of where the user has explored. Independent of any other improvements you might implement.

threading? or something else?

In a python 3.12 world, you could GET from an external webserver, or fork off another interpreter so you have a 2nd GIL. In a 3.13 world, you are free to experiment with relaxing the GIL constraint, even within a single process. Of course, there is also the possibility of always doing a tiny amount of incremental work on each frame update, so by the time the player wanders over to some new location, there is lots of terrain ready for them to gaze upon.
